# Flutter - Futurebuilder showing data only after reload

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-futurebuilder

I am using future builder as follows:

```
 FutureBuilder<List<SurveyModel>>(
                future: Provider.of<SurveyUtils>(context, listen: false)
                    .fetchSurvey(context),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    final List surveys = snapshot.data as List;
                    return ListView.builder(
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: surveys.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return surveyTile(
                          surveyModel: surveys[index] as SurveyModel,
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return const Center(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 100.0),
                      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Future function is as follows:

```
Future<List<SurveyModel>> fetchSurvey(BuildContext context) async {
    print('fetch survey function call');
    List<SurveyModel> surveys = [];
    final String body = await Provider.of<HiveDB>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchData(boxName: 'surveys', title: 'surveys') as String;
    print('fetched');
    final data = json.decode(body)['data'] as List;
    surveys = data
        .map((survey) => SurveyModel.fromJson(survey as Map<String, dynamic>))
        .toList();
    print('done');
    return surveys;
  }
```

I am getting data from future builder only after reloading unless I reload I only get Circular progress indicator. Also `print('fetch survey function call');` is not executed until reload.

Comment: Use streambuilder instead!

Comment: @Davis Would you explain why they need a StreamBuilder here?

Comment: I do not see any problem with your code.From what I get from the question is you want to get data seamlessly even without refreshing the page? If so use streamBuilder

Comment: I do not get data unless I flutter hot reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
future: Provider.of<SurveyUtils>(context, listen: false)
                .fetchSurvey(context),
```

You are not supposed to *create* the future in your build method. Your build method can be called many, many times and you don't want to fetch surveys *again* just because someone resized their browser window or turned their device to landscape mode.

Create a variable in your state that can hold this future. Then set this variable *outside* of your build method. If you have no specific trigger like a button, maybe `initState` is the right place.

In your `build` method, only reference this variable. This way, you will not trigger your Future over and over again if your build method if called.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a variable outside the build method and initialize it in void init() inside setState. And then pass it in the FutureBuilder's future parameter.

You can see the following tutorial:
https://youtu.be/LYN46233cws